# Using SVG icons in Angular2

Tags: angular

I've been wondering what is the best practice in Angular2 for using SVG icons.
I saw that currently there are 2 main methods:
1.Convert the SVG to fonts.
2. Inline SVG XML in the component.

We started using the fonts method using ICOMOON but our problem was that we have multi color icons and then we should create component for these icons only(for the other icons we used CSS attribute on SPAN/DIV)

Our problem with the Inline SVG method is that the code is a little messy(XML attributes in my template)

Are there any more methods that we can use?

Comment: this is a great article about svg in angular 2, please try this https://teropa.info/blog/2016/12/12/graphics-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 3):

I used this way to put svg icons and images in my website:

If you have image/icon with .svg extension , you can directly add it in Img tag by putting src. This way you can manage the svg code in a saparate file (yourIcon.svg).

```
<div>
    <img src="yourIcon.svg">
</div>
```

In case you want to control SVG Image/Icon Css Styles **dynamically** through user inputs/events on UI please check out this link:
[Angular 2 : Controlling SVG Image/Icon Css Styles dynamically through user inputs/events on UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42200443/angular-2-controlling-svg-image-icon-css-styles-dynamically-through-user-input)

Note 1: take care of the img source location. Root location is where your index.html file resides.

Note 2: Just to add, You can Edit the code of a svg file at any time. To view the code of your icon/image.svg, you have to use any editor (like Sublime) and you just have to open that .svg file. Below is a sample code of an image 'simpleCircle.svg' (Made by using Adobe Illustrator) that you will see if you open it in a editor. You can make any change you want and save it again:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version:     6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 175.7 177" style="enable-background:new 0 0 175.7 177;" xml:space="preserve">

   <style type="text/css">
    .st0{
       fill:#FFFFFF;
       stroke:#000000;
       stroke-width:8;
       stroke-miterlimit:10;
     }
  </style>
  <circle id="XMLID_1_" class="st0" cx="91.2" cy="87.2" r="75"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.when using the SVG file as an img don't you lose the ability to change things like colors or sizing?
My SVG comopoent has @input for the colors and sizing

Comment: Hey Meitark, You can edit the code of image just by opening it in any editor. I have added a new note (Note 2) in my answer. Have a look.

Comment: Hi Aman,
I want to have the ability to control the colors of the SVG in run time.
To do that  i need to set the st0 attributes in your example to be as Angular2 inputs of the SVG

Comment: You want to take input for the css attributes of a class (like .st0 here) from user interface dynamically and accordingly change the svg image without running app again ?

Comment: exactly,, things like change the icon color when user clicked on the icon

Comment: If you use Jquery in angular 2, you can do all this. I know there can be other ways too. I have tested it and added a link in my answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`ng-inline-svg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-inline-svg) module (or possibly other similar existing solutions) for this.

It is basically something in the middle - you will have your SVGs in separate files, that will be inlined when the page gets loaded, so you will be able to manipulate with it via JS/CSS.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/" inlineSVG="/assets/img/logo.svg"></a>
```

This will result in DOM like this:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" inlinesvg="/assets/img/logo.svg" routerlink="/" href="/">
    <svg width="105" height="29" viewBox="0 0 105 29" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        // ...
    </svg>
</a>
```

Comment: ng-inline-svg has been deprecated