# Angular 2 : Controlling SVG Image/Icon Css Styles dynamically through user inputs/events on UI

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular, svg

I used Jquery to control the Css styles of svg image dynamically in Angular 2.

**1: Control using events like mouse hover**

Below is a sample code for a simple circle .svg image with initial styles defined and a mouseover event on circle which will trigger 'func1' on hovering the circle:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
viewBox="0 0 175.7 177" style="enable-background:new 0 0 175.7 177;" xml:space="preserve">

<style type="text/css">
.st0{
   fill:#FFFFFF;
   stroke:#000000;
   stroke-width:4;
   stroke-miterlimit:10;
 }
</style>
<circle id="XMLID_1_" class="st0" cx="91.2" cy="87.2" r="10"    (mouseover)="func1()"/>
```

Now define this function: func1() in its corresponding component (.ts file) with the styles you want to be changed using jquery. It will look like this:

```
func1(){
   console.log("func1 has been called!");
   $(".st0").css({"stroke":"yellow", "fill": "blue"});
}
```

Try to explore other events also (like 'click').

**2. Control by taking form inputs**

If you want to change styles of svg using form inputs you should use dynamic binding.
Sample additional code (along with previous svg code) in template:

```
<form>
    Stroke<input type="text" name="stroke" [(ngModel)]="stroke">
    Fill<input type="text" name="fill" [(ngModel)]="fill">
    <button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Code need to be added in corresponding component (.ts file):

```
stroke:any;
fill:any;

submit(){
   console.log("submit called!"+ this.stroke+" and  "+ this.fill);
   $(".st0").css({"stroke":this.stroke, "fill": this.fill});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `ngStyle` directive

```
<circle [ngStyle]="{stroke:stroke, fill: fill}" 
    id="XMLID_1_" 
    class="st0" cx="91.2" cy="87.2" r="10"    
    (mouseover)="func1()"/>
```

Just use the `ngStyle` directive

```
<circle [style.stroke]="stroke"
        [style.fill]="fill" 
    id="XMLID_1_" 
    class="st0" cx="91.2" cy="87.2" r="10"    
    (mouseover)="func1()"/>
```

Try to avoid using jQuery with Angular2.

Comment: Hi Günter, Thanks for the answer but this is like I have to put inline styles. What if I have all the styles in a separate file (Which is the case most of the times) and I just want to add class names. Can we control style attributes in that case also without JQuery?

Comment: You can add/remove CSS classes this way, so different styles get applied depending on the added class(es). I'd suggest trying to avoid using jQuery with Angular2. Also the code in your question doesn't indicate styles in separate files.